# Rails inserting incorrect `order` statement

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to retrieve a list of the 21 most viewed photos. I have this code in my controller:

```
@photos = Photo.where("group_id = (?)", params[:target_id]).order('view_count ASC').limit(21)
```

and it outputs the following SQL:

```
SELECT  "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE group_id = ('205')  ORDER BY "photos"."timestamp" DESC, view_count ASC LIMIT 21
```

Where is the `timestamp DESC` query coming from and how do I get rid of it? The photos are being returned chronologically instead of by view count..

Comment: check if any default scope is written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are using a `default_scope` in your `Photo` model. If that's so, try using:

```
@photos = Photo.unscoped.where("group_id = (?)",params[:target_id]).order('view_count ASC').limit(21)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `default scope` you should use `unscoped` to override or remove that default scope.

**`unscoped(): Returns a scope for the model without the previously set scopes.`**

**`default_scope(scope = nil) :- Use this macro in your model to set a default scope for all operations on the model.`**

```
@photos = Photo.unscoped.where("group_id = (?)", params[:target_id]).order('view_count ASC').limit(21)
```

then the the query should be,

```
SELECT  "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE group_id = ('205')  ORDER BY "photos"."view_count" ASC LIMIT 21
```